# Kali Linux won't boot from USB

Tags: boot, kali-linux

I've been trying to boot Kali Linux from my 8gb USB. I get to where I'm supposed to choose from one of the various options: Live, Persistent, Persistent With...... etc etc. I go on and select one, say the first: Live. However, Kali goes on and on forever whenever the text stops running up the screen and a mouse cursor appears on a blank screen. Nothing changes after this. It remains like this.

What could be the problem and how can I fix this. Thank you all in a dvance.

Comment: Can you post the whole output of `ls -R` inside the USB?

Comment: did you try disabling modesetting in the grub command line before you boot (edit command line and say if you have an nvidia gpu, add **nouveau.modeset=0**, don't know what you do for amd)

Answer (score 3):

Two initial considerations are

- You should use a USB3 device and port if possible as USB2 may be too slow
- Make sure that the ISO that you used includes support for your graphics card or integrated graphics.

If you would like to try killing X and going to command prompt you could use Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F2 to switch to a command prompt and restart the login manager.

You can accomplish this by executing

```
sudo service lightdm stop && sudo startxfce4
```

or

```
sudo xkill -a && sudo startxfce4
```

If restarting the windowing environment does not work directly, and your hardware is supported, then there is likely something wrong with your Xorg configuration. Get to the command prompt again with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

End the X session again with

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

or

```
sudo xkill -a
```

Backup your current configuration

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
```

Then have Xorg attempt to create a new config file and overwrite the current configuration

```
sudo X -configure && cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Attempt to start XFCE again

```
sudo startxfce4
```

If the autoconfig does not work then post the old and new config file here. As well you should install the lspci command as follows.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pciutils
```

Then please run lspci and post the output here. You can save the output as follows.

```
lspci > lspciOut
```

Then save it to any writable mounted device.